# WCF calls and TransparentProxy methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am working on an app that used WCF to make SOAP calls to a service.  I was doing some debugging and am confused about a bit of code, specifically how the SOAP call is made.

The SOAP calls work fine but there is a line which I do not understand:

```
return base.Channel.BeginSetProductType(request, callback, asyncState);  //What does this line actually do?
```

What caught my attention is the fact that base.Channel has a `BeginSetProductType` method but I do not see where it is defined.  I cannot step into this line when I try debugging but did see that base.Channel is a `TransparentProxy` class, which has a reference to a `RealProxy` class.  Reading up on these it looks like they are heavily used by WCF for remote calls.

Can anyone give me at least a high level understanding of what is happening here?  It might just be deep in how WCF works but am still curious.  Not sure where the code that handles the actual call to the endpoint is made.

Below are the relevant classes.  I tried to make it as simple as possible.  They were created using svcutil based off a wsdl file.

```
[System.CodeDom.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0.")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceCOntractAttribute(Namespace="", Configuration="TestSoapService")]
public interface TestSoapService
{
  [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="",ReplyAction="*")]
  [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
  SetProductTypeResponse SetProductType(SetProductTypeRequest request);

  [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="",ReplyAction="*")]
  System.IAsyncResult BeginSetProductType(SetProductTypeRequest request, System.AsynCallback callback, object ayncState);

  SetProductTypeResponse EndSetProductType(System.IAsyncResult result);
}


[System.CodeDom.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0.")]
public partial class TestSoapServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TestSoapService>, TestSoapService
{
  public TestSoapServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address) : base(binding, address)
  {
  }

  System.IAsyncResult TestSoapService.BeginSetProductType(SetProductTypeRequest request, System.AsynCallback callback, object ayncState)
  {
    return base.Channel.BeginSetProductType(request, callback, asyncState);  //What does this line actually do?
  }

  public System.IAsyncResult BeginSetProductType(SetProductType SetProducType, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
  {
    SetProductTypeRequest inValue = new SetProductTypeRequest();
    invalue.SetProductTyp = SetProductType;
    return ((TestSoapService)this).BeginSetProductType(inValue, callback, asyncState);
  }
}
```

The SOAP call is made like so:

```
TestSoapServiceClient.BeginSetProductType(new SetProductType {ProductType = "TEST});
```

Comment: The code for **BeginSetProductType** in WCF refers to creating a channel factory in a WCF client using the **ChannelFactory<TChannel> class**, and then starting an asynchronous operation by calling the **Channel.BeginSetProductType** method to set the product type. This is usually the case in the WCF service interface:  [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginSetProductType(SetProductTypeRequest request, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    void EndSetProductType(IAsyncResult result);